# App trava após terminar laço em Thread

Tags: java, android

Olá, eu fiz um app no Android Studio que quebra as frases em palavras e armazena em um vetor usando o split. Depois eu fiz um laço de repetição usando o while para que ele exiba palavra por palavra, porém acontecia um problema, o aplicativo congelava a tela, e depois de ter feito todo o laço a atualizava e acabava só aparecendo a ultima palavra do vetor. Pra resolver isso eu usei uma Thread, resolveu, ele atualiza, porém o app trava quando acaba.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View view){
                        Thread t1 = new Thread(){
                            int wpm;
                            String frase;
                            int numbers;
                            int i;
                            @Override
                            public void run(){
                                numbers = Integer.parseInt(txt2.getText().toString());
                                wpm = 1000/(numbers/60);
                                frase = txt1.getText().toString();
                                final String palavras[] = frase.split(" ");
                                i = 0;
                                while(i++ < palavras.length){
                                    try {
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                label.setText(String.valueOf(palavras[i]));
                                            }
                                        });
                                        Thread.sleep(wpm);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        t1.start();
                    }
                }
        );
```

Logcat:

> 05-02 01:33:16.142 6738-6738/com.exsapps.readfast E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.exsapps.readfast, PID: 6738
>       java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=122; index=122
>           at com.exsapps.readfast.Main$1$1$1.run(Main.java:48)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: Esse teu sleep, qual valor fica alí no wpm? Talvez esteja indo um valor alto e você esteja pensando que o app está travando

Comment: Colocar um Log pra ver qual está sendo o valor desse wpm

Comment: esse WPM são palavas por minutos, a pessoa informa o tanto de palavras por minuto, e eu ali transformo pra milisegundos. E a cada palavra que ele mostrar, ele da um sleep, em milisegundos.
O problema nao é esse, o aplicativo agora roda normal, só que depois que termina de mostar todas as palavras do vetor pausadamente o aplicativo fecha. "Aplicação parou." no celular.

Comment: Ah tá, ele para de funcionar, pensei que só ficava travado, vai no logcat e copia aqui qual o erro, lá mostra, fica mais fácil pra ajudar

Comment: Adicionei o logcat na pergunta, att.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Li o comentário do Carlos, e tentei e deu errado, após isso, adicionei a variável de controle do laço for declarada no começo do código e no laço usei apenas for(i = 0; i < palavras.length; i++){} e o problema foi resolvido, o aplicativo roda, e após sua execução, ele não trava.

Codigo:

```
    public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    EditText txt1;
    EditText txt2;
    TextView label;
    public int i; // < -- Essa foi a solução
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
        txt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        txt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener(){
                    public void onClick(View view){
                        Thread t1 = new Thread(){
                            int wpm;
                            String frase;
                            int numbers;
                            @Override
                            public void run(){
                                numbers = Integer.parseInt(txt2.getText().toString());
                                wpm = 1000/(numbers/60);
                                frase = txt1.getText().toString();
                                final String palavras[] = frase.split(" ");
                                for(i = 0; i < palavras.length; i++){
                                    try {
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run(){

  label.setText(String.valueOf(palavras[i]));
                                            }
                                        });
                                        Thread.sleep(wpm);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        t1.start();
                    }
                }
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: Por que você usou uma nova thread ao invés de usar uma asynctask, ou algo que processe em background ?

Comment: Desculpa, provavelmente é que eu comecei meus estudos tem 1 mês, to aprendendo sobre threads essa semana, mas vou pesquisar a respeito! Obrigado!

Comment: Opa sem problemas colega ! Eu também sou novo em programação, então perguntei para saber o conceito ! rs

Answer (score 1):

O problema deve ser `while(i++ < palavras.length)`
ou seja, i está sendo comparado e **depois** incrementado, então, dentro do loop o valor final de `i` vai acabar sendo `palavras.length` que é um indíce inválido.

Aconselho usar um `for` como em (bem convencional, todo programador vai reconhecer):

```
for (int i = 0; i < palavras.length; i++) {
    final String palavra = palavras[i];
    ...
        label.setText(palavra);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Eu já havia feito desse jeito, porém aparecia a seguinte mensagem: "error: local variable i is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final" e o app nem compilava. Coloquei ela como final e também da outro erro. Mas vendo sua resposta, tentei novamente, e ta lá o mesmo erro, então pensei em declarar a variável de controle do laço como public lá em cima, e depois usar o for(i=0;i<palavras.lenght;i++) executei o aplicativo, ele rodou como de costume, e no final não parou de funcionar como estava acontecendo.
Obrigado!